# Use boost libraries in appveyor

Tags: boost, appveyor

I am writng a script for appveyor.
I need to use boost libraries in my c++ project.
In my appveyor script I have written these lines:

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0;%INCLUDE%


cd C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0
dir
.\bootstrap.bat
.\b2 --with-iostreams runtime-link=static --build-type=complete

set LIB=C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib;%LIB%
```

but that gives an error on `.\bootstrap.bat`

```
.\bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.
Command exited with code 1
```

you could find the log of appveyor at https://ci.appveyor.com/project/srbcheema1/vcf-demo/build/1.0.32

my CMakeLists.txt is like :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9)
project (reader-demo CXX C)
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE  "Release" CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build" FORCE)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
add_executable(reader uncompress.cpp)
```

how could I use the boost libraries in appveyor ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to manually install a recent version of boost. It is [already there](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/windows-images-software/#boost) and precompiled. Just make sure your to pass the correct path to your build configuration for using boost headers and the appropriate linkder flag. For a cmake build, this would be

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0 path\to\your\source
```

Comment: @libgr but i am unable to build it from there https://ci.appveyor.com/project/srbcheema2/win-demo

Comment: No need to build it. It's precompiled. I updated the answer, too.

Comment: @libgr it seems like they are not precompiled. As I cannot find the directory `C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib` there. If they are precompiled could you please tell me the location of `libboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-s-x32-1_67.lib` file. you could see error in https://ci.appveyor.com/project/srbcheema2/win-demo/build/1.0.11

Comment: thanks @libgr I got those libraries. they are in `lib32-msvc-14.1` directory instead of `stage\lib`.